# iOS GCM received wrong JSON

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

Why always the result in iOS is

```
{
"collapse_key" = "do_not_collapse";
"content_available" = true;
from = 936308038806;
notification = "{\"sound\":\"default\",\"title\":\"Title\",\"body\":\"This is body\"}";
priority = high;
to = "MY_CODE";
}
```

Please help me why array 'notification' changed to the string

Answer (score 0):

Your server is converting notification array to JSON, which is causing it to show as string in iOS.

Try

```
$data['notification']=json_decode($data['notification'], true);
```

Comment: Yes i did, I 'echo' the result and get  a correct JSON structure. But in iOS notification is a string instead of an array.

Thanks, Gunjot !

Comment: Try

$data['notification']=json_decode($data['notification'], true);

before sending PUSH from your PHP server